# Class design program compiling but does not run completely

Tags: java

Firstly this program, has void main() but even after writing it, when I am running it there is no option to run it through main..Secondly even if I select the other option available there, i.e., new Convert(String w), it is not running properly.I entered CAT and it is showing an error message that says cannot find symbol- variable cat...But the thing is that the program has compiled with no syntax errors in BlueJ..This is a program to input a word and then change each of its characters to its next character ...so cat as an input should give dbu as the output... Please help me to understand where have I gone wrong..Here is the code for your reference....

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
  
  public class Convert
   {  

    String word;
    String result="";
 
   Convert(String w)
    
    {  

       word=w;
      }
    void Word()
    {
        
        char ch;
        int l=word.length();
        for(int i=0; i<l;i++)
        {
            ch=word.charAt(i);
            result+=(char)(((int)ch)+1);
        }
        
    }
    void display()
    { 
        System.out.println("The original word:"+ word);
        System.out.println("The newly coded word:"+ result);

     } 
    
     void main()

     {  

       Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Enter a word");
       String s=sc.next();
       Convert ob=new Convert(s);
       ob.Word();
       ob.display();

     }
    }
```

Comment: main must be public and static: `public static void main()`

Comment: Thank you ...Can you tell me what changes should be done in this code so that a word which has Z in its spelling gets changed to A

Comment: [`String.replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char))

Comment: if(ch=='Z') result+='A';

Comment: You got it wrong...(example: input:- cat 
 Output:- dbu 
 here ‘c’ got changed to ‘d’, ‘a’ got changed to ‘b’ and ‘t’ got changed to ‘u’. 
Note that if the letter is the last alphabet then it has to be changed 
to the first alphabet i.e., ‘z’ is to be converted as ‘a’)

Comment: You got it wrong...(example: input:- cat Output:- dbu here ‘c’ got changed to ‘d’, ‘a’ got changed to ‘b’ and ‘t’ got changed to ‘u’. Note that if the letter is the last alphabet then it has to be changed to the first alphabet i.e., ‘z’ is to be converted as ‘a’)

Comment: for higher offsets of Caesar cipher use `charToAdd= (ch-'A' + offset)%26 + 'A'`

Answer (score 1):

main function should be `public static void main(String[] args)`

About your question in the comments, to rotate Z to A and z to a:

```
if (word.charAt(i) <= 'Z') {
    res += (char) (word.chartAt(i) + 1 - 'A') % 26 + 'A');
} else {
    res += (char) (word.charAt(i) + 1 - 'a') % 26 + 'a');
}
```

You can also use ascii values, i.e 'A' = 65, 'a' = 97.